# Swift language: How to call SecRandomCopyBytes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

From Objective-C, I could do this:

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:length];
int result = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, length, data.mutableBytes);
```

When attempting this in Swift, I have the following:

```
let data = NSMutableData(length: Int(length))
let result = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, length, data.mutableBytes)
```

but I get this compiler error:

```
'Void' is not identical to 'UInt8'
```

The data.mutableBytes parameter is rejected because the types do not match, but I can't figure out how to coerce the parameter (and I'm presuming it's somehow safe to do).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
let data = NSMutableData(length: Int(length))
let result = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, length, UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(data.mutableBytes))
```

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 5**

```
let count: Int = <byteCount>
var data = Data(count: count)
let result = data.withUnsafeMutableBytes {    
    SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, count, $0.baseAddress!) 
}
```

**Swift 4**:

```
var data = Data(count: <count>)
let result = data.withUnsafeMutableBytes { mutableBytes in
    SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, data.count, mutableBytes)
}
```

Comment: You can use `nil` instead of `kSecRandomDefault`.

Comment: The Swift 5 produces an error `Overlapping accesses to 'data', but modification requires exclusive access; consider copying to a local variable`. The solution is to replace `data.count` with whatever you are passing as the `<count>`

Comment: Thanks for the notice @AndyIbanez, I've improved the answer for Swift 5.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4 version:

```
let count = 16
var data = Data(count: count)
_ = data.withUnsafeMutableBytes {
    SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, count, $0)
}
```